# Sanitize input with FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING

Tags: php, http-post, forms, sanitize

I'm getting mad writing some code for sanitize the data which come from a form.
In the form I have a input field named "sender_countryCode" that could only contains 2 or 3 text characters like USA, FR, EN, ...
the following code should block everything different from a string but if i write "my text" in the field nothing pass the filter!

```
if  (isset($_POST["sender_countryCode"])){
    $var    =   $_POST["sender_countryCode"];
    $var    =   stripslashes($var);
    $var    =   htmlentities($var);
    $var    =   strip_tags($var);
    $var    =   filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $sender["countryCode"] = $var;
    unset($var);
};
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your code limiting it to 2-3 characters? `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` simply strips tags and optionally encodes, it has nothing to do with limiting the length of the string

Comment: you're right but let take the max lenght for tomorrow, the main problem is that in the form I write "my string", the code show me $sender["countryCode"] as empty!

Comment: Try using a break point or just `echo $var;` after each statement to see where it is failing. I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works :) ...sorry im abit late, but i saw it was not answered. Here is my solution.:

```
function maxLengthCheckUp($this) {
    if ( strlen($this) <= 4){
        return TRUE;
    }
}
if (isset($_POST["sender_countryCode"]) 
  && !preg_match('/\s/',$_POST["sender_countryCode"]) 
  && maxLengthCheckUp($_POST["sender_countryCode"])) {
    $var    =   $_POST["sender_countryCode"];
    $var    =   stripslashes($var);
    $var    =   htmlentities($var);
    $var    =   strip_tags($var);
    $var    =   filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $sender["countryCode"] = $var;
    echo $sender["countryCode"];
    unset($var, $sender);
};//end of if(...
```

CREATE YOUR FORM WITH THE FOLLOWING ELEMENTS:

```
<input type="text" name="sender_countryCode" id="sender_countryCode" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
```

submit your form...creating a normal form....just use my php code above. Try it out :)